# How do I use the API to check MembershipType and "active" status?

Tags: api

I've been tinkering with API explorer and examples https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/blob/4.5/api/v3/examples/ but can't find a solution.

Via **Smarty** I'm looking to print some text "blah blah blah" via the .tpl of a Donation (Contribution) Page if the current viewer of that page has:

1. a membership of a certain type (example: "1")
2. that is "active" (current or new status)

Note that this contribution page is not membership related, it is for donations.

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assuming you're doing this with a .tpl.extra file. I tried mocking this up in the API Explorer and found a couple shortcomings, namely the lack of support for arrays in smarty, and the inability to set a contact ID field to the magic "user_contact_id" value. [Here's a fix](https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/6369) for both those issues.

The upshot is you can now do this:

[image: API Explorer with member params]

Instead of the boilerplate `{foreach}` loop you can do a simpler conditional. Here's the full code you would use:

```
{php}
  $this->assign("param_status_id", array('IN' => array("New", "Current", "Grace")));
{/php}
{crmAPI var='result' entity='Membership' action='get' contact_id="user_contact_id" membership_type_id=1 status_id=$param_status_id return="id"}
{if !empty($result.values)}
  Blah blah blah...
{/foreach}
```

Comment: contact_id="user_contact_id" was essential.  never seen that before.  thanks!  Where is that documented?

Comment: Beats me, but now it's the default in the api explorer, nice n easy to find :)